# How to add schema name to Query annotation in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, oracle11g, spring-data-jpa

Currently I have such piece of code, which doesn't work, since I have to add schema name before each table in a query(like `DEV.DASHBOARDS_METADATA`):

```
public interface DashboardMetadataDao extends CrudRepository<DashboardMetadata, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT D FROM DASHBOARDS_METADATA D " + 
           "INNER JOIN FAC_DASHBOARDS_LINK DL ON D.ID = DL.DASHBOARD_ID " +
           "INNER JOIN FIRMS F ON DL.FAC_ID = F.FAC_UNIT_ID " + 
           "INNER JOIN USERS U ON U.FIRM_ID = F.FIRM_ID WHERE LOWER(U.USERID) = LOWER(:userid)")
    public Set<DashboardMetadata> findByUserId(@Param("userid") String userId);
}
```

The problem is that schema name differs from database to database (DEV/QA/PROD). Normally I use component's method which prepend schema's name to each table during query generation. How can do this using annotations?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use different `@Profile` one for each environment

Comment: "D.*" is invalid JPQL. JPQL would be "SELECT D FROM ..."

Comment: @NeilStockton yes, you're right. I already fixed it. However I still can't find a way how to deal with schema names. As far as I understand from '@RC. comment, anyway I have to change profile name before deploy webapp to  another instance.

Comment: The schema is defined in the persistence unit, and in the annotations for the entities. So you can have one persistence-unit for prod and one for dev. Such things should not be present in runtime code

Answer (score 4):

Hibernate has a variable that can be used in native queries to get schema name called: `{h-schema}`

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/chapters/query/native/Native.html#sql-global-catalog-schema You can just put `{h-schema}table` in your query. I think you have to convert it to a native query.

Answer (score 3):

Below Code Snippet worked for me

```
@Query(
              value = "select *\n" + 
                    "from {h-schema}TABLE-A r left join {h-schema}TABLE-B p on r.ID=p.ID\n" + 
                    "left join {h-schema}TABLE-C pe on p.ID=pe.ID\n" + 
                    "left join {h-schema}TABLE-D e on pe.ENT_ID=e.ENT_ID\n" + 
                    "where r.role_type='Provisioning'", 
              nativeQuery = true)
```